# Who/What controls G1 Combiners?

Tags: transformers

Transformers Combiners are groups of 2-6 bots who combine into a more powerful super-bot. In later continuities, the combined super-bot is controlled by one specific member of the group. For example, Ruination from Robots in Disguise is controlled by Mega-Octane; In Transformers: Energon, the combined mode is controlled by whoever forms the top/torso.

I have been unable to find any such rule - if there even is one - for Generation 1 Transformers. Does any one Transformer/member of the group control the combined mode? Is the combined mode its own separate consciousness? Bruticus (the combined form of the the Combaticons) refers to himself in the third person. Even the Constructicons speak of Devastator almost as a separate entity.

> SCRAPPER: The Constructicons form Devastator, the most powerful robot.  We should rule.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the first gen, the combined robot was the result of the merged bodies and minds of the 6 Constructicons.  His [mental capability](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Devastator_%28G1%29) was limited to only the actions that all 6 could agree upon at any given time.  He was not a solely sentient being of himself.  Most of the other combiners were similarly limited in intelligence.  Superion, the combined form of the Aerialbots, for example, was a primitive intelligence limited to two base commands:  Destroy the Decepticons and protect the humans.

Answer (score 4):

I just remember seeing this [episode of the cartoon](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Grimlock%27s_New_Brain) where [Grimlock](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Grimlock_%28G1%29#Generation_1_cartoon_continuity) transferred a newly acquired intelligence to [Computron](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Computron_%28G1%29#Cartoon_continuity), a Combiners formed of the [Technobots](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Technobot_%28G1%29) he had just conceived.

In this episode, the Combiners appeared as a separate entity.